# script type="text/html" include HTML from a file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<script type="text/html">` like below:

```
<script type="text/html" id="id">
        // I want to import HTML from a file here
</script>
```

Please suggest any other solution than `<object>, <iframe> and <embed>`
Those tags are messing up my CSS as they insert their own HTML, BODY and other elements.

I would prefer NOT using jQuery. Although not so adamant about it.

**EDIT:**

`script type="text/html"` is MUST as I am using templates to route between the pages. And the template is identified by the "id" of this `script type="text/html"` element.

Comment: Is the linked page on the same domain as the source, or is this cross-domain?

Comment: You can have your html as jspf and directly include the file using `<%@ include file="fileName.jspf"%>`. If its external file/content then you need to use iframe.

Comment: @dave It is on the same domain. Just different folder.

Comment: "*I would prefer NOT using jQuery.*" Any particular reason? It certainly is possible without it, but the wrappers jQuery provides for AJAX operations are super convenient.

Comment: @esqew how can it be done in jQuery? I am not so adamant about not using it.

Comment: may I know why downvote? I could not find any solution which would solve this exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you do consider utilizing jQuery, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will do the trick:

```
$( "#id" ).load( "path/to/file.html" );
```

<sup>[JSFiddle illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/gntLxL97/)</sup>

Comment: You are changing the question itself by that answer. My question is not just to load a html page. I want to load it in my `script type="text/html"` element.

Comment: `$( "script[type=text/html]" ).each(function() {$(this).load($(this).text())});` should load it for every script of type `text/html`.

Comment: @liam_ Cannot do this. As I have multiple `script type="text/html" ` elements. Each with different template.

Comment: The whole point is that it works with multiple `script type="text/html"` elements? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: @liam_ I have multiple `script type="text/html"` with different ID's. Based on those ID's I have to plug in the template (HTML pages). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is on the same domain, I suggest you use ajax to recover it.
Like this:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var remote_html_container = jQuery("#wrapper");
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "my-page-url",
      success: function(data){
        remote_html_container.html(data);
      }
    });
</script>
```

What it does is load the page's output through jQuery and "paste it" into the div#wrapper.

EDIT:
It's indeed way easier with the load function:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery("#wrapper").load("my-url.html");
</script>
```

Comment: How do I include it in the `script type="text/html"` tag?

Comment: Your script/html has no reason to be there anymore. Just put a div with a chosen ID and replace this id inside the javascript part.

Comment: Ok then just change #wrapper by #id.